# python giving function as output?

Tags: python, output

my python function was supposed to merely print variables from a multitude of functions into a single line, but Target.get_target_type is outputting as something I don't really understand so I have no idea how to fix it. The expected output was a string literal of 'x' or 'y'.

The output:

```
Target behavior:     <function Target.get_target_type at 0x102d89620> Pursuer behavior:      X   Mis-Match
```

from function:

```
def interaction_report(self):   
        print("Target behavior: \t", Target.get_target_type,  "Pursuer behavior: \t", self.pursue_type, "\t", self.match_string)
```

refers to:

```
def get_target_type(self):      
        return self.__target_type
```

Comment: wouldn't you want `self.get_target_type()` rather than `Target.get_target_type`?

Comment: no because that particular one is referring to another module

Comment: Then I think you're going to need to show us more code.  Utimately, python is printing the representation of the function `Target.get_target_type` because that's what you're asking it to do.  I suspect that you want to print the return value of that method, but to get that you'll need an instance of `Target`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually call the function (e.g. `Target.get_target_type()` instead of just `Target.get_target_type`.  If you don't call it, then you just end up with a reference to the callable function object itself.

Comment: That still won't fix it (It'll be a `TypeError` since you didn't pass anything for `self`).